# Android - v.getId() in Context Menu returning 'false'

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a context menu. The function v.getId() is supposed to return the id, but does not - instead it returns 'false'.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, v.getId());  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Save Notification");  
}  

@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getTitle()=="Save Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Save Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
    else {return false;}  
return true;  
}  

public void function1(int id){  
    //Stuff
} 

public void function2(int id){
    if (id == R.raw.tedcake){
        Toast.makeText(this, id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The buttons were registered for a context menu elsewhere in the code.

Why is it returning false?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that `false` is being returned?

Comment: The toast, and the name of the first menu item.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue...in the folder res/values you should have a file ids, for each item there are four attributes (name, type, format, value). In my case the field "value" was "false"

Answer (score 1):

1. It's impossible that `v.getId()` returns `false`. It returns an integer, which won't be a boolean **ever**.
2. On the other hand, what's this supposed to do?: `menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, v.getId());`. You are passing `v.getId()` in the last parameter, which will cause problems (since it's waiting for an String resource identifier, not a view resource identifier). Maybe you meant `menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Save Ringtone");`?

With regards to your question: "why am I getting false?". It's because of this:

```
if(item.getTitle()=="Save Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
else if(item.getTitle()=="Save Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}
else return false;
```

It's a common problem for new Java developers. The problem is here: `item.getTitle()=="Save Ringtone"`; specifically the problem is `==`. **That's not the way you compare objects in Java**. You have to use the `equals` method, this way:

```
if(item.getTitle().equals("Save Ringtone")){function1(item.getItemId());}  
else if(item.getTitle().equals("Save Notification")){function2(item.getItemId());}
else return false;
```

If you use the `==` operator with objects, you are comparing the references to the object, not the object.

Comment: I was just using that to see what v.getId() was returning.

Comment: Thanks, but the v.getId() is still coming out as a boolean.

Comment: @Joel are you kidding. Read this carefully: v.getId() WON'T return a boolean EVER! Because it returns an integer, not a boolean. It's completely impossible. It's more feasible the God existence than that you are saying. Did you try `equals` method?

Comment: So totally feasible and even likely?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I've tried the equals method also, but it comes AFTER where I'm checking for what v.getId() equals.

Answer (score 1):

`view.getId()` returns an int, not false. If the view does not actually have an ID, it returns NO_ID, which is a constant equal to -1. One issue I see with your code is that you are comparing strings using ==. You should use equals instead. There's plenty of related SO posts about that, if you want to know more.

Comment: An int? So it won't be something like R.raw.sound?

Comment: R.raw.sound is an integer, if you haven't noticed :D

Comment: ...is it?! :L I'm more used to Python, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

it's because most functions in android take **string** not **int**, so does toast.
try **String.valueOf(view.getId())** to toast u will see the id. ur welcome

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to you.  `view.getID()` will always return an integer, so I decided to see what would happen if I cast the integer to a string in the toast.  This method will show you the ID.  I believe the reason you see false is because the toast errors out when you supply an  integer instead of a char sequence.